# Python install packages: Couldn't install packages with pip install command

Tags: python, pip, conda, python-3.8, anaconda3

I've been trying to install the vertex package on my conda environment by using the pip install command on the anaconda prompt, but I keep getting the following warnings and errors:

```
pip install vertex

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/vertex/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/vertex/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/vertex/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/vertex/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/vertex/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vertex
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vertex
```

Screenshot from the anaconda prompt:
[image: The errors from the anaconda prompt]

I tried to extend the timeout of the pip command and got the following warnings and errors:

```
pip --default-timeout=1000 install vertex

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/vertex/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/vertex/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/vertex/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/vertex/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/vertex/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vertex
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vertex
```

Screenshot from the anaconda prompt:
[image: The errors from the anaconda prompt]

I've had the same problem installing scipy about a week ago but I managed to bypass it by using the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scipy
```

It succeeded and then I added the conda-fronge channel to my env. Trying to install the vertex package using the conda install command I got a message that it couldn't find the vertex package in the current channels and I didn't manage to find the appropriate channel for this. The command line:

```
conda install vertex

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - vertex

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Either ways I couldn't install the vertex package in my conda environment.

Thanks in advance to all helpers :)

Answer (score 1):

This package does not seem to be available on Anaconda Cloud and its [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/Vertex/#history) history is several years old with no updates. Skimming the project's [README](https://github.com/twisted/vertex), it does not look to be in an actively-maintained state, so you're probably not going to be able to install it via a package manager (if at all).

Comment: Yes, you're right but I know that people in my class managed to install the package without any problem (I need this for a  course project). Given that I had problems also installing scipy using the pip command a week ago I don't think that's the reason for the install to fail. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try avoiding mixing multiple packages sources. Doing that should decrease probability of dependency problems. To my understanding in your environment you now have 3 sources:

- conda
- conda-forge
- pip

For a clean conda environment pip installs the package without errors.

```
conda create -n vertex-env python=3
conda activate vertex-env
pip install vertex
pip list
```

Using command sequence above I managed to successfully install  the vertex package, although I did not verify the run-time.

```
$ pip list
Package        Version
-------------- -------------------
attrs          20.3.0
Automat        20.2.0
certifi        2020.12.5
cffi           1.14.4
constantly     15.1.0
cryptography   3.3.1
hyperlink      21.0.0
idna           3.1
incremental    17.5.0
pip            20.3.3
pycparser      2.20
PyHamcrest     2.0.2
pyOpenSSL      20.0.1
setuptools     49.6.0.post20210108
six            1.15.0
Twisted        20.3.0
Vertex         0.3.1
wheel          0.36.2
zope.interface 5.2.0
```

Comment: I tried what you wrote and it still didn't work. I've also tried to uninstall anaconda completely and reinstall it, and then to do what you wrote but it still didn't work. still thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Given how old this package is, there is little reason to believe it will work with any Python 3 versions. In fact, [searching for `print` commands in the repo code](https://github.com/twisted/vertex/search?q=print), we find some lacking parentheses, which implies Python 3 incompatibility. Hence, instead try a Python 2.7 build and just let Pip resolve everything other than the Python and Pip:

**vertex.yaml**

```yaml
name: vertex
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
  - free
dependencies:
  - python=2.7
  - pip
  - pip:
    - Vertex
    - service_identity
```

Then from shell (e.g., bash):

```bash
conda env create -n vertex -f vertex.yaml
conda activate vertex
```

This gets it so Vertex installs and doesn't throw errors when loading some of the modules I found in the tests (e.g., `from vertex import q2q`), but I didn't run the actual tests.

Comment: @Niv that sounds correct. Ensure that your spacing in the file is exactly matching what I provided (YAML is sensitive to whitespace). Since you're on Windows, you likely need to start an Anaconda Prompt session, rather than the default Command Prompt.

Comment: Yeah it was something like that. It still throws the same errors as in the post. For my class project requirements I'm gonna need to have python 3.7.x